# Php Curl Cookie login

Tags: php, curl, cookies, authentication

Hi i need to login to webpage using cookie the cookie is in this format key=login value=id=3694385&pw=d9d51ab066c09c2404&cks=bfb964
Here is my code for login but it fails to login using this cookie.(Note cookie is constant for 24 hrs and i dont want to login using username and password)

Here is my code

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init('http://up.net/');
echo $curl;
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'login=id=3694385&pw=d9d51ab066c09c2404&cks=bfb964');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$page = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $page;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your cookie format is wrong. Cookies are delimited by semicolons, not ampersands.

Comment: i needed to encode the cookie into html form like this id%3D3694385%26pw%3Dd9d51ab066c09c2404%26cks%3Dbfb964